iOS App crashes after successful Xcode Cloud build
Using react native (0.73.7). Have been successfully using React native -> Xcode (15.3, local) build+archive+distribute -> TestFlight workflow to test my iOS app.
Today I tried setting up Xcode Cloud (uses Xcode 16.1) workflow. Figured out some common errors, involving post-clone.sh etc and finally the Xcode Cloud build was successful.
With this build, when installed via TestFlight, the app opens with the usual welcome screen, where there is a button for the second screen. However, the app crashes upon clicking this button. No particular error message, except that the App crashed. Just to verify that my code is not broken, I successfully tested the app as usual in local Xcode (Version 15.3) Simulator as well as installing through my previous manual Xcode build/archive/distribute workflow.
I’m a bit clueless as to what’s going wrong with the Xcode Cloud setup.
Note: one thing I’ve noticed, in my local environment, my node version is 19.8.1 whereas on Xcode Cloud via post-clone script, it installs the latest node. But that didn’t result in any build or archive failures.
If anyone has gone through similar problem, would love some inputs.
Thanks in advance for your time!
ci_post_clone.sh
# Navigate to the project root
cd ../../

echo "===== Installling CocoaPods ====="
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=TRUE
brew install cocoapods
echo "===== Installing Node.js ====="
brew install node

# Install dependencies
echo "===== Running yarn install ====="
npm install
CI="true" npx expo prebuild

echo "===== Running pod install ====="
cd ios
pod install

Update: Crash data



You should be able to view the crash log in Xcode (Window -> Organizer -> Crashes) or in App Store Connect. Hard to say much else without seeing this.

Thanks for pointing out where to find crash logs. I couldn't understand much though. Updated the post with the screenshots.

The second screenshot looks like build errors. Where are those coming from?

I have no idea. Strange part is if I do the build/archive manually in Xcode and distribute to TestFlight, everything works fine! It is only the Xcode Cloud build that is giving this issue. Xcode Cloud build succeeds, archive is created, TestFlight is updated, even the first home page is loaded. Upon a button click (which navigates to a different screen), it crashes!

I mean where did you find those build errors to be able take a screenshot of them?

I opened 'Crashes' in the Organizer, clicking on a specific error and it opens it in the Xcode editor of that project! I took the screenshot after it opened in the project.

Right, but the build errors are separate from the crash error. They indicate issues with the local project. Does it actually build locally?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
